# onfocusout alternative?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function editLabel(source) {
        source.innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="' + source.innerHTML + '"/>';
        source.onclick = null;
        source.children[0].focus()
    }
    function setLabel(source) {

        if (source.children[0].value != '') {
            source.onclick = function () { editLabel(source); };
            source.innerHTML = source.children[0].value;
        }

    }
```

Then in my asp label:

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" onfocusout="setLabel(this);" onclick="editLabel(this);" Text='<%# Bind("GroupDescription") %>'></asp:Label>
```

This works fine in Chrome and IE but does not work in Firefox.

This is because Firefox only supports onblur.

I have tried to add onblur to the label and textbox but it does not work.

What could I do?

Thanks

Comment: use jQuery, it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Which JQuery function would do this?

Comment: focusout - http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Comment: what you have tried with onblur??

Comment: Check out [jEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html)

Answer (score 0):

Look into jQuery, and binding functions to events. Namely examine hover, blur, and focus. A framework like jQuery is necessary if you want to do any real web development.

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

http://api.jquery.com/blur/

http://api.jquery.com/focus/

For an example, see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/turiyag/fQV3p/

```
$("#blurry").hover(function() {
    log("Hover In!");
}, function(){
    log("Hover Out!");
});
$(":text").blur(function() {
    log("Blurred from textbox with value: " + $(this).val());
});
$(":text").focus(function() {
    log("Focus given to textbox with value: " + $(this).val());
});
```